# Find all Filtered by Nested in elasticsearch

Tags: filter, nested, elasticsearch

I want to make a query, looking all equal to "something" but other than that I can filter by fields: "idcategoria", "idinstitucion" and "idtipooa".

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    website:
        client: default
        types:
             ofertas:
                 mappings:
                     id: { boost: 3 }
                     nombreoa: { analyzer: snowball }
                     titulo: {boost: 3}
                     duracion: {boost: 3}
                     uniduracion: {boost: 3}
                     email: {boost: 3}
                     caracteristicas: { analyzer: snowball }
                     requisitos: ~
                     planestudio: ~
                     matricula: {boost: 3}
                     cuota: {boost: 3}
                     estado: {boost: 3}
                     dirigidoa: {boost: 3}
                     url: {boost: 3}
                     idareaestudio:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombre: { boost: 5 }
                     idcategoria:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombre: { boost: 5 }
                     idinstitucion:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombreinstitucion: { boost: 5 }      
                            nombresede: { boost: 5 }
                     idmodalidadoa:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombre: { boost: 5 }  
                     idniveloa:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombre: { boost: 5 } 
                     idtipooa:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                            nombre: { boost: 5 }                   
                 persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: FrontEnd\AplicacionBundle\Entity\Oa
                    provider: ~
                    finder: ~
                    repository: FrontEnd\AplicacionBundle\Repository\OaRepository
```

I tried:

```
> { 
"query": {
    "filtered": {
          "query":  {  "text": { "_all":   "Aboga"}},
   "filter": {  "term": { "idtipooa.nombre": "Universitaria" }}
}
}}
```

But it has not worked.
Please if anyone can help ... Thank you!

Comment: I'll guess this is elastic search. If it is so, you should mention that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite get what you want to achieve. What would you expect as a result?

Comment: I need is to find a word in all content, but filter by idtipooa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idtipooa` is a nested field, so in order to search it you need to wrap your `term` filter into [nested filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter/).

Comment: I tried: {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
        "filter" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "idtipooa",
                "query" : {
                    "bool" : {
                        "must" : [
                            {
                                "match" : {"idtipooa.nombre" : "Universitaria"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "_cache" : true
            }
        }
    }
}It has not worked

Comment: That should work. Please, add a complete example with some sample data to your question.

Comment: {"_index":"website","_type":"ofertas","_id":"3","_score":0.32260805, "_source" : {"id":3,"nombreoa":"Abogacia","titulo":"Abogado","duracion":"5","uniduracion":"As","email":"info@info.com","caracteristicas":"El abitraje\n","matricula":"2196","cuota":2196,"estado":"V","dirigidoa":null,"url":null,"idareaestudio":{"nombre":"Abogacia"},"idcategoria":{"nombre":"Abogada"},"idinstitucion":{"nombreinstitucion":"UDE - Universidad de la Empresa","nombresede":"Central"},"idmodalidadoa":{"nombre":"Presencial"},"idniveloa":{"nombre":"Grado"},"idtipooa":{"nombre":"Carrera Universitaria"}}

Comment: Rebe, I just tested it with your data and pieces of your mapping - it works. https://gist.github.com/imotov/737176fd5a0f60730db8 Make sure that mapping is applied correctly to your index.

Comment: I expected the results to be zero, because I consult "Universitaria" and not "Carrera Universitaria"

Comment: You are using default analyzer that splits fields into words, and if any of the words match your query, the record matches your query. If you want the match on entire field and as is, you should index this field as `not_analyzed`.

Comment: Imotov, i tried to do the mapping, but I get error, do not know how to put not_analyzed.

Comment: I have updated the gist with an example - https://gist.github.com/imotov/737176fd5a0f60730db8

Comment: I went great! Thank you very much! You're the best! "not_analyzed" was my solution!